# Sync adapter API calls fail when app is not running

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, okhttp, android-syncadapter

I am using sync adapter to sync data to/from a server. I am using Interceptor class of okhttp3 as below:

```
 public class CustomRequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {


    @Inject
    SharedPreferenceManager sharedPreferenceManager;

    public CustomRequestInterceptor() {
        MyApp.component().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().header("Accept", "application/json").header("Authorization", getToken()).build();

        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Sending request %s on %s%n%s", request.url(), chain.connection(), request.headers()));

        Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received response for %s in %.1fms%n%s", response.request().url(), (t2 - t1) / 1e6d, response.headers()));

        return response;
    }

    private String getToken() {
        String token = sharedPreferenceManager.getAccessToken(MyApp.getContext());
        if (token != null) {
            return "Bearer " + token;
        }
        Log.e("REQUEST", "Token is NULL");
        return "";
    }
}
```

When I run the app I foreground or background all works well. But when I close the app, as I am using sync service, the API calls still get fired. The issue I am facing is when the app is closed all the API's fail as the header for access token is missing (As per Charles logs), but I do see that in the Android logcat the header with access token is getting printed in my logs.

```
 Log.d(TAG, String.format("Sending request %s on %s%n%s", request.url(), chain.connection(), request.headers()));
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. My guess is that as the app is not running it cannot access the shared preference.